# esint - Step-by-step instructions for editing space between integral signs

Tags: fonts, packages, miktex, esint

I just don't know how to proceed in order to change the horizonal space between integral signs, when adding `\iint`or similar commands. I've read the documentation, but my knowledge of TeX structure limits me. May anyone help me in a detailed way?

OS - Win7 64bit
TeX environment - MikTeX package (TeXWorks included)
TeX editor - TeXnic Center

Comment: I don't understand which space you're about: between the different integral signs that compose a multiple integral? between the integral sign and the integrand? bor the bounds/domain of integration?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The package `esint` uses specific symbols for `\int`, `\iint` and `\iiint`; you can't change their spacing without changing the font.

Comment: Hello egreg. In that case, i'd appreciate that you teach us how to change the font for that purpose.

Comment: Don't load `esint` if you don't want to use the symbols it provides...

Comment: Hello cfr. I want to use the symbols provided by esint. The problem i have is that i want to change the horizontal space between integral signs (documentation says it can be done), i don't know how...

Comment: @Danieltatis I see nothing in `texdoc essint` about changing spacing and as egreg says these are characters in a font, changing the space is like changing the space between the dot and the bar in `i` it can not be done from within TeX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the link is the following: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/esint

Comment: @Danieltatis sure that's ctan but it's also in texlive and `texdoc esint` shows the local copy of the same documentation. either way the multiple integral signs are a single character so there is no space to adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to change the spacing between the integral symbols (for double and triple integrals) provided by `esint`, because they are *single* characters in the special font associated to the package.

What you can do is to modify the spacing provided by `amsmath`, which is defined by the `\intkern@` macro. For instance you can do as follows; the extra `-4mu` kern is only inserted in display style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
% the original definition in amsmath
%\def\intkern@{\mkern-6mu\mathchoice{\mkern-3mu}{}{}{}}
\def\intkern@{\mkern-8mu\mathchoice{\mkern-4mu}{}{}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
$\int\quad\iint\quad\iiint\quad\idotsint$
\end{center}

\[
\int\quad\iint\quad\iiint\quad\idotsint
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the change, the output would be

[image]

For comparison, here's the output with `esint`.

[image]

For completeness, here is the font table of the special integral font provided together with the `esint` package.

[image]